# RDS Mysql ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user @IP (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

[This is not a duplicate question]

I have created a RDS MySQL instance with same Security Policy and under same VPC as my EC2 instance.

However when i am trying to access the Instance from EC2 machine i am getting error:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'User'@'IP' (using password: YES)

Not sure if i am missing Anything.

In MYSQL setup we can resolve this error with added Privileges for User on the IP.Not sure how can we resolve this since i am unable to access the Instance itself.

Anyone faced this issue before?.

I have followed the Document: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html#MySQL.Procedural.Importing.Create.RDS.Database

Comment: This error is pretty straightforward.  You're using the wrong username or password.  If you're using the administrator account, you can reset the password in the console.

Comment: I am pretty sure the User and password we are using are correct.

Comment: Is this a new instance?  Or is it an existing instance that formerly worked but now is no longer accessible?  Are you in fact using the admin user credentials or a different user?  Do any credentials work?  More information is needed.

Comment: Michael, You were right at the first place.Thanks for the info.The user name and password i used was for instance.I never seen the user it created for Mysql DB which was different.Its working now.

Comment: @vipink. Can you please let me know which other user name and password you used. I am stuck with the same error. Thank You!

Comment: I have faced similar issue. Not sure whether it's applicable to you.

I was getting this error, when I was trying to connect with sudo privilege.
I tried connecting again with same command except from normal ubuntu user from my ubuntu setup on ec2 instance; and it worked.

Comment: i created a "duplicate" image to recover lost PEM.  now the new one will not connect to the DB.  I updated the HOST in the user table on the DB but it still will not connect.

Answer (score 7):

```
mysql -h dandy-dbamazonaws.com[...] -u root -p
```

`-h` - put your endpoint
`-u` - username you set for your local mysql (root in my case). Don't confuse it with instance name
`-p` - after you hit 'enter' enter the password for your instance (the one you set up during instance creation)

hope it will work! that's how I resolved this issue

Comment: You can find the `Master username` (you can use it for `-u` parameter) by clicking on your RDS instance name > tab Configurations;

Answer (score 3):

Maybe late but I had the same problem today.

1. Confirm the MasterUsername, with the AWS CLI running `aws rds describe-db-instances` or in the web console, showing the cluster details on the configuration tab.
2. Confirm the password, if you are using linux consoles (bash) some some characters may be problematic like `#` or `!`.
3. If you are using ssl connection you can't use `--ssl-mode=DISABLED`. You have to use `--ssl-mode=VERIFY_CA` (if you are connecting to endpoint) or `--ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY` (OR VERIFY_CA) if  are connecting to server endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The goofy ones always get you: I experienced the same problem after changing the master password but let slip the important fact that by default changes don't take effect until the next maintenance window.

In my scenario I was connecting to an Aurora MYSQL serverless v2

- Check you are connecting to the cluster writer instance endpoint
- Modify the master password and apply changes immediately